# Is there a way to apply conditional in an Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to provide a solution to display the highest score of student in a class.

```
function highestScore (students) {
```

// code here
    }

```
    // TEST CASE
     console.log(highestScore([
      {
     name: 'Daisy',
     score: 90,
     class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
      name: 'Alexander',
      score: 85,
      class: 'wolves'
   },
   {
    name: 'Sergio',
    score: 74,
    class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
     name: 'Anabelle',
     score: 78,
     class: 'wolves'
   }
 ]));

 From the parameter, the function would return the name of each class and 
 display the highest student's name and score of that student.

  function highestScore (students) {
    var classes = {};
    var scores = [];
   for(i=0; i<students.length; i++){
     var inputClass = students[i].class;
     var inputScore = students[i].score;
     var inputName = students[i].name;
     var classScore = [];
     var isExist = false;

     var object = Object.values(class);
     return classScore;
   }


 // TEST CASE
 console.log(highestScore([
   {
     name: 'Daisy',
     score: 90,
    class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
     name: 'Alexander',
     score: 85,
     class: 'wolves'
   },
   {
     name: 'Sergio',
     score: 74,
     class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
     name: 'Anabelle',
     score: 78,
     class: 'wolves'
   }
 ]));

 The result would show something like this.
 // {
 //   foxes: { name: 'Daisy', score: 90 },
 //   wolves: { name: 'Alexander', score: 85 }
 // }
```

Comment: Beware edge case: multiple students (in the same class) with the same highest score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce` into an object whose keys are class names, whose values are the currently highest student for that class. On each iteration, if no value at the class exists yet, assign the student - otherwise, assign the student only if the student already at that class has a lower score:

```js
function highestScore(arr) {
  const highestByClass = arr.reduce((a, student) => {
    const { class: className, score } = student;
    if (!a[className] || a[className].score < score) {
      a[className] = student;
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(highestByClass);
}


console.log(highestScore([
   {
     name: 'Daisy',
     score: 90,
    class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
     name: 'Alexander',
     score: 85,
     class: 'wolves'
   },
   {
     name: 'Sergio',
     score: 74,
     class: 'foxes'
   },
   {
     name: 'Anabelle',
     score: 78,
     class: 'wolves'
   }
]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. But is there any way I can solve the problem without using const and reduce? Since I am still in an entry level and we are required to use simple methods and simple loop only.

Comment: For these purposes, `const` works identically to `var`. It's just declaring a variable name. (It has additional protections, in that `const` variables aren't hoisted, nor can they be reassigned, but that doesn't matter for the code here. Best to always use `const` by default when declaring variables)

Comment: `.reduce` *is* the most appropriate method by far for this sort of thing. On every iteration, it takes in the accumulator (the `a`), which is either the initial value passed in (the `{}` here) or what was returned on the last iteration (the `return a`). If you're more comfortable with `forEach`, you can `const a = {}; arr.forEach((student) => { ... }); return Object.values(a);`

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is as follow.

```
    function highestScore (students) {
         var object = {};
     var result = [];
     for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){
    var nameInput = students[i].name
     var scoreInput = students[i].score
     var classInput = students[i].class

if(object[classInput] === undefined){
  object[classInput] = {
    name: nameInput,
    score: scoreInput,
  }
}
for(var j=0; j<students.length; j++){
  if(students[j].class === object[students[i].class] && students[j].score > object[students[i].class].score){
    object[classInput] = {
    name: students[j].name,
    score: students[j].score,
    }      
  }
}
```

}

```
    return object;

   }
```

However, I wasn't able to insert the new value if the students coming after has higher score than the initial.

`// TEST CASE
console.log(highestScore([
  {
    name: 'Dimitri',
    score: 90,
    class: 'foxes'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alexei',
    score: 85,
    class: 'wolves'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sergei',
    score: 94,
    class: 'foxes'
  },
  {
    name: 'Anastasia',
    score: 78,
    class: 'wolves'
  }
]));`